# magento mysql server has gone away SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data

Tags: magento-1.9

site is very very slow and we got this error in  backend:

```
General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` WHERE (`value` LIKE '{{base_url}}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are trying to get this? There is a method to get any setting form `core_config_data`

We get current store id (of course you can choose the on you need)

```
 $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()
```

And then we retrieve value of setting - you have to check path of the setting if it's proper one.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('web/unsecure/base_url', $store_id)
```

So to sum up there is a shortcut of course

```
$value = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/unsecure/base_url', Mage::app()->getStore())
```

Comment: Please, change `Mage::getStoreConfig(''web/unsecure/base_url', $store_id)` to `Mage::getStoreConfig('web/unsecure/base_url', $store_id)` (the odd quotation mark)

Comment: that's right I didn't notice that, thanks!